# pipe: atlassian/jenkins-job-trigger:0.1.1

Tags: python, pipe, bitbucket, jenkins-job-dsl

I am calling pipe in my script section to call a jenkins job from BB yml. The stage (in BB) is getting success however, no job got triggered in Jenkins

```
- step: &functionalTest
name: functional test
script:
- pipe: atlassian/jenkins-job-trigger:0.1.1
variables:
JENKINS_URL: '<<my jenkins URL>>'
JENKINS_USER: '<<my jenkins username>>'
JENKINS_TOKEN: '<<my jenkins token>>'
JOB_NAME: '<<my jenkins jobname>>'
```

No error but Jenkins job isnt triggered

> --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_HTTP_ORIGIN" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_UUID" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE="$BITBUCKET_REPO_IS_PRIVATE" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE="$BITBUCKET_WORKSPACE" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER_UUID" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_BRANCH="$BITBUCKET_BRANCH" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID="$BITBUCKET_REPO_UUID" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY="$BITBUCKET_PROJECT_KEY" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG="$BITBUCKET_REPO_SLUG" 
> --env=CI="$CI" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER="$BITBUCKET_REPO_OWNER" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_STEP_RUN_NUMBER" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER="$BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN="$BITBUCKET_GIT_SSH_ORIGIN" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID="$BITBUCKET_PIPELINE_UUID" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_COMMIT="$BITBUCKET_COMMIT" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR="$BITBUCKET_CLONE_DIR" 
> --env=PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN="$PIPELINES_JWT_TOKEN" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID="$BITBUCKET_STEP_UUID" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL="$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" 
> --env=DOCKER_HOST="tcp://host.docker.internal:2375" 
> --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_SHARED_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes"
>
> --env=BITBUCKET_PIPE_STORAGE_DIR="/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/.bitbucket/pipelines/generated/pipeline/pipes/atlassian/jenkins-job-trigger"
>
> --env=JENKINS_TOKEN="secureToken" 
> --env=JENKINS_URL="https://jenkins.p.morconnect.com/online/job" 
> --env=JENKINS_USER="sarathnagarajan" 
> --env=JOB_NAME="online-mymorrisons-automation/sonar-reporting" 
> --add-host="host.docker.internal:$BITBUCKET_DOCKER_HOST_INTERNAL" \ bitbucketpipelines/jenkins-job-trigger:0.1.1 Unable to find image
> 'bitbucketpipelines/jenkins-job-trigger:0.1.1' locally
> 0.1.1: Pulling from bitbucketpipelines/jenkins-job-trigger b4d181a07f80: Pulling fs layer a1111a8f2ec3: Pulling fs layer
> ed53099fbce6: Pulling fs layer dc539afda2c1: Pulling fs layer
> 77bc0d833cb6: Pulling fs layer ea1ffd508d33: Pulling fs layer
> e201113b9485: Pulling fs layer 00bf2b3661fe: Pulling fs layer
> d7f9ccdbfde4: Pulling fs layer dc539afda2c1: Waiting 77bc0d833cb6:
> Waiting ea1ffd508d33: Waiting e201113b9485: Waiting 00bf2b3661fe:
> Waiting d7f9ccdbfde4: Waiting a1111a8f2ec3: Verifying Checksum
> a1111a8f2ec3: Download complete ed53099fbce6: Verifying Checksum
> ed53099fbce6: Download complete b4d181a07f80: Verifying Checksum
> b4d181a07f80: Download complete ea1ffd508d33: Verifying Checksum
> ea1ffd508d33: Download complete dc539afda2c1: Verifying Checksum
> dc539afda2c1: Download complete 77bc0d833cb6: Verifying Checksum
> 77bc0d833cb6: Download complete 00bf2b3661fe: Verifying Checksum
> 00bf2b3661fe: Download complete e201113b9485: Verifying Checksum
> e201113b9485: Download complete d7f9ccdbfde4: Verifying Checksum
> d7f9ccdbfde4: Download complete b4d181a07f80: Pull complete
> a1111a8f2ec3: Pull complete ed53099fbce6: Pull complete dc539afda2c1:
> Pull complete 77bc0d833cb6: Pull complete ea1ffd508d33: Pull complete
> e201113b9485: Pull complete 00bf2b3661fe: Pull complete d7f9ccdbfde4:
> Pull complete Digest:
> sha256:2cebbe81f365578b04a955fb1be97083181863d1755f9fd0ca122e0d7e8c0629
> Status: Downloaded newer image for
> bitbucketpipelines/jenkins-job-trigger:0.1.1
>
> ```
> WARNING: Could not find released pipe version for atlassian/jenkins-job-trigger. Data matched: {}
> ```
>
> INFO: Submitting jenkins job... ✔ Pipe has finished successfully.

Comment: I tried adding debug logs as mentioned in the other Forum Also wait='true' for jenkins job to complete. It seems, there are certain redirections as per org policy. 

However, there is one other message thats unclear for me
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/pipe.py", line 145, in <module>
pipe.run()
File "/pipe.py", line 136, in run
self.wait_for_job(build_response.headers['Location'])
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/requests/structures.py", line 54, in __getitem__
return self._store[key.lower()][1]
KeyError: 'location'
any help will be hugely appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to the fact that i am using a non-proxy'ed jenkins url where BB is redirecting to sign in forcefully despite of using jenkins user_name and jenkins_token

Adding a debug: 'true' revealed this truth.
Also worth adding wait: 'true' rather having default wait time as 120 secs (changeable though)